# Instantiating Bitmap causes download call in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

I have stumbled upon a (for me) kind of strange behavior when istantiating a bitmap in MVC 3.

```
var bm = new Bitmap(path); //This line causes a download popup when using IE9
```

The file is typeless and about 15 byte in size.

I can't see this behavior in any other browser.

Does anyone have a good explanation for this?

Comment: What's the URL and what are the contents?

Answer (score 1):

This line cannot cause the popup in IE directly as there is no way for server-side code to 'call' browser. You must be returning a response from your action.

Have you tried debugging your code?

You probably have an uncaught exception and content-disposition header set.

More code from your action would be useful.